# JPA Query. Path array of parameters that need to be selected

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I need to choose dynamically which parameters should be in query output. Is there any way to do something like that:

```
@Query(value = "select params = :arrayOfParams from myTable", nativeQuery = true)
User findparamsAll(@Param("arrayOfParams") List<String> params);
```

For example I have Entity User with name, surname, address, age.
In one case I want to choose only name, in other sername, age and address. And e.t.c

Comment: findAllByParamIn(Iterable<String> params)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create interfaces to represent a View like the following:

```
public interface UserView {
    String getName();
}
```

and then put it as the return value in your repository:

```
UserView findAll();
```

You can also implement a dynamic projection the following way:

```
T findAll(Class<T> type);
```

and call it like

```
userRepository.findAll(UserView.class)
userRepository.findAll(User.class)
```

Read more about projection here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections

Edit

You can be truely dynamic if you use javax.persistence.Tuple as return value in your interface:

```
Tuple findAll();
```

However you have to extract the data yourself then:

```
tuple.get("NAME", String.class)
```

However that still selects all fields from the database. If you truely want dynamic sql queries you can call EntityManager to create a dynamic SQL:

```
entityManager.createQuery("select ..."), Tuple.class).getResultList();
```

If you do that make sure to not be vulnerable for SQL injection!

Comment: thanks for answering, but I think i need bit different. 
For example I have Entity User with name, sername, address, age.
In one case I want to choose only name, in other surname, age and address. And e.t.c
In article u send, I guess I need to write to many different interface to emulate dynamically output of rows

Comment: I added some truly dynamic possibilities, but since Java doesn't really have dynamic objects anyway I am not sure if that's really a good way to do things.